# multiple instances of emacs overwrite recentf-list

Tags: emacs, recent-file-list

I have quite usual recentf config.

```lisp
(use-package recentf
  :config
  (setq
    recentf-save-file "~/.cache/emacs/recentf"
    recentf-max-saved-items 100000
    recentf-max-menu-items 5000
    )
  (recentf-mode 1)
```

The problem is that I run multiple emacs instances. Unfortunately, it overwrites recentf file when the instances are closed.

```
instance 1 loads recentf version 1
instance 2 loads recentf version 1
... some times passed instance 1 and instance 2 do some work ...
instance 1 get closed and saves recentf version 3
instance 2 get closed and saves recentf version 4
```

Problem is that when instance 2 closes it does not read recentf of version 3. As a result files added by version 3 are lost. You can imagine it gets worst with more than one instance. How can I make recentf work correctly with multiple instaces.

Comment: It's a good question. I'm not sure of a great way to handle this. If you don't get a good answer here then consider filing an enhancement request for Emacs, using `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: I suppose you are already using emacsclient to launch multiple instances?

Comment: @Rorschach I just launch `emacs`, do not use emacs server, or anything like this.

Comment: using emacs server should solve the problem if that is an option for you

Comment: @Rorschach I have used to work with multiple instances, this workflow works well for me. I prefer not to use the server.

Comment: Haven't tried it, but in theory couldn't you add on to both `recentf-track-opened-file` and `recentf-track-closed-file` to save and then load the `recentf-save-file`?  Inefficient but might do ya?

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody still encounters this issue:

Try the [sync-recentf](https://github.com/ffevotte/sync-recentf) package. I have not used it but it looks like what you want.

---

Every Emacs instance maintains the variable `recentf-list` which is populated by calling `recentf-load-list`. Opening files will then append the new filepath to this variable but not to the file. Calling `recentf-save-list` will then cause this variable to be written to the recentf-file you specified. Note that this writing out is not appending to the file but rather replacing its content.

Simply calling `recentf-load-list` before saving is not an option either because this will override the unique files from the `recentf-list`.

The aforementioned package works around this limitation by creating a dummy file on top of `recentf-list` effectively seperating this variable into 'old and new'. When calling `recentf-save-list` a new `recentf-list` is created by the following steps:

1. Save the new filepaths
2. Override `recentf-list` with the values from `recentf-file`
3. Append saved filepaths to `recentf-list`
4. Override `recentf-file` with the values from `recentf-list